# Is there a bootable program to find out detailed hardware info?

Tags: bootable-media

I am wondering if there is a bootable program which can be run from a USB stick to get detailed hardware info of my PC?

Comment: Have you tried searching? Product recommendations are off-topic on SE, unless it is a very specific problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always use a bootable [Linux USB drive](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/) (I recommend Ubuntu).

#### How to view the system specs in linux

Open terminal and type `sudo dmidecode --type`. Don't click <kbd>Enter</kbd> yet!  after `--type`, you can write `bios` or `system`, etc. to view the related specs.
For example: `sudo dmidecode --type bios` will display the BIOS specs.

Complete list of "What can I write after `--type`" (common parameters are in **bold**):

- **Memory**
- **BIOS**
- **System**
- **Base Board**
- **Chassis**
- **Processor**
- Memory Controller
- Memory Module
- Cache
- Port Connector
- System Slots
- On Board Devices
- OEM Strings
- System Configuration Options
- BIOS Language
- Group Associations
- System Event Log
- Physical Memory Array
- Memory Device
- 32-bit Memory Error
- Memory Array Mapped Address
- Memory Device Mapped Address
- Built-in Pointing Device
- Portable Battery
- System Reset
- Hardware Security
- System Power Controls
- Voltage Probe
- Cooling Device
- Temperature Probe
- Electrical Current Probe
- Out-of-band Remote Access
- Boot Integrity Services
- System Boot
- 64-bit Memory Error
- Management Device
- Management Device Component
- Management Device Threshold Data
- Memory Channel
- IPMI Device
- Power Supply

Comment: I believe that this is the command: `sudo dmidecode`. http://linux.die.net/man/8/dmidecode

Comment: updated @Джеймс_C웃

Answer (score 8):

You can burn an iso image of any Linux distribution, and use commands like:

- [**`lshw`**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lshw): Will give you a very comprehensive list of hardware and settings.
- [**`lspci`**](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/lspci8.html): Will show you most of your hardware in a nice quick way. It has varying levels of verbosity so you can get more information out of it with `-v` and `-vv` flags if you want it.
- [**`dmidecode`**](http://linux.die.net/man/8/dmidecode): as mentioned in answer of @matan129
- [**`lscpu`**](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman1/lscpu.1.html): List available cpus and their caracteristics.

---

### HDT Project

> HDT (stands for *Hardware Detection Tool*) is a Syslinux com32 module that displays low-level information for any **x86 compatible system**. It provides both a command line interface and a semi-graphical menu mode for browsing.

[image]

Project page: [`www.hdt-project.org`](http://www.hdt-project.org/)

Download the file **.iso** (approximate size 1.3 mb) and burn on usb.

Comment: Thanks. Will its bootable cd run on 64-bit systems (new laptops etc)?

Comment: The original web site is down but someone mirrored it from web.archive.org, so one can get the image files at https://github.com/knightmare2600/hdt